# How to find the drop down arrow of QComboBox is clicked?

Tags: python, pyside2, qcombobox

I have a QComboBox and I need to set up a list of names when the drop-down arrow of that QComboBox is clicked. So is there any function of PySide2 to find out whether the user has clicked that drop-down arrow, after this I would like to get the index of the user selection. If anyone has any idea about doing this either in PySide2.

Answer (score 1):

You have to detect the position of the mouse click and verify that the complexcontrol is QStyle::SC_ComboBoxArrow:

```py
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class ComboBox(QtWidgets.QComboBox):
    arrowClicked = QtCore.Signal()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super().mousePressEvent(event)
        opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionComboBox()
        opt.initFrom(self)
        opt.subControls = QtWidgets.QStyle.SC_All
        opt.activeSubControls = QtWidgets.QStyle.SC_None
        opt.editable = self.isEditable()
        cc = self.style().hitTestComplexControl(
            QtWidgets.QStyle.CC_ComboBox, opt, event.pos(), self
        )
        if cc == QtWidgets.QStyle.SC_ComboBoxArrow:
            self.arrowClicked.emit()


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = ComboBox()
    w.addItems(["option1", "option2", "option3"])
    w.show()

    w.arrowClicked.connect(
        lambda: print("index: {}, value: {}".format(w.currentIndex(), w.currentText()))
    )
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```